# Rasa error when set use_entities to [ ] in domaim.yml

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I want certain intents to not have any entities and I get an error when trying to do this according to the documentation https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/domain#ignoring-entities-for-certain-intents

The domain.yml file

```
intents:
  - greet:
    use_entities: []
  - goodbye
```

I get the following error

```
/home/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rasa/shared/utils/io.py:97: UserWarning: Loading domain from 'domain.yml' failed. Using empty domain. Error: 'In the `domain.yml` file, the intent 'greet' cannot have value of `<class 'NoneType'>`. If you have placed a ':' character after the intent's name without adding any additional parameters to this intent then you would need to remove the ':' character. Please see https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/domain for more information on how to correctly add `intents` in the `domain` and https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/domain#intents for examples on when to use the ':' character after an intent's name.'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing an indent:

```
intents:
  - greet:
      use_entities: []
  - goodbye
```